# open(filename) not working when the python script is called from php

Tags: php, python-2.7, xampp-vm

I have a php file in my XAMPP-VM server which looks like this:

```
<?php

$message = exec('python testPython.py');
echo($message);

 ?>
```

the testPython.py file looks like this:

```
f = open('data.txt', 'w+')
f.write('test')
print('hello')
f.close()
```

When I run the php file like so localhost/testPHP.php, the testPython.py file gets stuck on line one and does not move on. When I commented out the first, second, and last line of code, the program worked fine and printed out "hello." Interestingly, when I run the testPython.py file from terminal like this `python testPython.py` it works. It opens data.txt and writes "test." Does anyone know how I could fix this problem?

note: I know that I could easily do the same thing from php without executing a python file at all but this post is just showcasing my problem. I need to open a file in a python file that I have already put a lot of work into.

Comment: Perhaps the working directory is not what you expect in the case of running from PHP.

Comment: If stderr reveals nothing, the python interpreter itself offers verbose and debugging output.

Answer (score 0):

first 
you can make a file call it runpy
and put this on it

```
python testPython.py
```

and then in ur php run

```
exec('bash runpy');
```

second
make sure the folder is set to 777, because when you run a cmd using exec you run it as the apache user www-data, while in the terminal as the root/admin that why it's work there and not on the php, so just make sure to set permission to 777